# How to run IDB.exe -forward without hanging ANT

Tags: fdt

I've followed [this tutorial](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/2012/06/7602/) on how to debug using USB.

There is one small issue, when I run the target to forward the USB port, it hangs the FDT JRE, as this task never ends. Here is the task

```
<target name="04. forward ports for USB debug">
    <exec executable="${FDTProjectSdkPath}/lib/aot/idb/idb" >
        <arg value="-forward" />

        <!-- LOCAL_PORT -->
        <arg value="7936" />

        <!-- REMOTE_PORT -->
        <arg value="12345" />

        <!-- DEVICE_HANDLE -->
        <arg value="1" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

I managed to get this working by running this forward command in a command line window.

Has anyone run into this kind of issue? I need to be able to run this forward command without hanging the JRE.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Are you able to add a link to a sample project (it can be simple). I don't quite follow....